# Can I add more login infos? Login panel C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, authentication

I made simple login form without database and there is only one username/password info, Can I make more than just one user/pass?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.

                  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> users = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            users.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ime1", "lozinka123"));
            users.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("niko", "niko123"));


            if (users.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)))
            {
                ucitavanje uczu = new ucitavanje();
                uczu.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Vaše korisničko ime ili lozinka nisu točni! Pokušajte ponovno!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've [dejavu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48323022/1997232).

Comment: Your edit makes it so your question does not make sense anymore. your new code (which you just copied from the answer) already accepts more than one username and password.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i wanted to show Ctznkane525 my code because it's not working and try to fix it. error that shows up when i debug is The type name 'List<>' does not exist in the type 'List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>'

Comment: @trackgg then add the code as an edit, not replace an existing code. Also did you remember do to `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of your file?

Answer (score 0):

This is highly unorthodox, so I hope you have a reason for that.

You can have a

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.


            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> users = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            users.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("info", "pass32821"));
            users.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("user2", "password2"));


            if (users.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)))
            {
                loading load = new loading();
                load.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed!");
            }
```

Comment: And If I let's say want another login credits (for example - username: user, password: password123) where do I have to put it in this code you gave me? :D

Comment: see updated example...im not too found of the not using database or encryption on the passwords...but its doable

Comment: thanks, but now when I try to debug it throws error: The type name 'List<>' does not exist in the type 'List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>'

Comment: check my updated code above to see what I put in there :)

Comment: i assume it works...if it does...please "accept" my answer...on screen option...usually though you dont change the question to look like the answer...makes it look very misleading for those who might want to see this question in the future...id recommend reverting the question

Comment: I just wanted to show you my code right now, and it doesn't work for some reason, it shows this error The type name 'List<>' does not exist in the type 'List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>'

Comment: to the top of your C# file - add this line "using System.Collections.Generic;"